# When I plug my earbuds into my macbook pro, the sound in the left side is "Fizzy"

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

Like I said in the title, whenever I plug my earbuds (or any earbud/earphone) into my macbook pro the sound on the left side only puts out a hiss-like (Fizzy) sound. I've plugged my earbuds into my iPhone and other devices that play music and it sounded fine, but it's just my macbook. I've already tried resetting the PRAM and that didn't work. The right side sounds fine, and my macbook's speakers are fine. If anyone has any good suggestions it would be very helpful and appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Interference of some type?

Comment: Maybe there is something inside the headphone jack causing causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A quick test to narrow down the cause.

1. Launch Audio Midi Setup [Applications/Utilities]
2. In the Audio Devices panel, click the item on the left that shows the small speaker icon when your headset is plugged in. [I don't have a headset, but from my picture below, it's the TonePort item that has the correct icon assigned to it]

[image]

3. Then on the right, click Output, then Configure Speakers.
4. Set each speaker to the opposite of what it currently says - from the 2nd  picture, set 1 to 2 and 2 to 1.
5. Click Apply, then Done.

[image]

6. Test your audio playback.
   If the 'fizzing' has swapped sides, it's the computer or playback software.
   If it stays in the same ear-piece, it's the headset or the physical connection.